# soft body mesh has too much friction

Tags: physics, soft-body

I've created a soft body with a hole inside so that it can glide down along a rod. But for some reason the soft body is not gliding...

[image]

The friction value of the soft body is 0 as well for the rod.
I also tried to prevent a deform of the opening by select a vertex group for the Edges > Springs option but that doesn't help either:

[image]

Here is link to the blend file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MWBkVi3LtUpCFg_Zxy9b0WxAULloCcEI

Any idea?

Thx!
Steven